# Q: how to deploy from Travis to Google Cloud Build?

Tags: google-app-engine, deployment, travis-ci, google-cloud-build

I have a trigger on Google Cloud Build for build a docker image and deploy it to the Container Registry and I have a Travis CI for running the tests. My purpose is to **connect** them in way of Travis runs the tests first, and when it's done and, of course all the tests pass, it deploys it to Google Cloud and the Cloud Build will do the docker build and the rest of the job.

Currently, I have a travis.yml that looks like the following:

```
language: csharp
mono: none
dotnet: 3.1.202
sudo: required
addons:
  apt:
    packages:
    - dotnet-sdk-3.0

before_install:
  - openssl aes-256-cbc -K $encrypted_a3c2492b5906_key -iv $encrypted_a3c2492b5906_iv -in gce.json.enc -out gce.json -d
install:
   - dotnet restore OnlineRetailer.sln

branches:
    only:
     - Testing

script:
 - dotnet build OnlineRetailer.sln
 - dotnet test TestCore/TestCore.csproj

 deploy:
  provider: gae
  project: resolute-land-274909
  keyfile: gce.json
```

I've added the OpenSSL line what I got after the Google service key encryption. The `gce.json.enc` is on GitHub as well, so I suppose Travis should see this file.
A strange thing: If my travis file contains the deploy field, the Travis do not do anything. Doesn't even notice the changes.

I have followed these 3 different descriptions:
https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/google-app-engine/
https://cloud.google.com/solutions/continuous-delivery-with-travis-ci
https://unhashable.com/continuous-deployment-to-google-app-engine-using-travis-ci/

None of them worked for me somehow.

Am I missing something, or doing something wrong?
Any suggestion is very welcomed!

Edit: 
Or if I cannot solve this way, is there any way, to have a fully working CI/CD pipeline on Google Cloud? 
I know that the trigger is supposed to be like a CD, but I couldn't find a proper documentation about how to set up a CI on Google Cloud.

**Update:**
Yesterday, I managed to hit the Travis with the deploy field in the .travis.yml file, but when it hits the `- openssl aes256-cbc...` command in the `before_install` the CI is fails. As I saw, this has been a big issue since 2016 due to windows encryption method. Solution would be set up a Linux VM and do there the file encryption and after that it *may* work. So I gave up on Travis CI-Google Build combo.

I'd rather do the whole CI/CD on Google Build.
Here's my cloudbuild.yaml I'm using currently:

```
steps:
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/dotnet
    entrypoint: 'bash'
    args:
        - '-c'
        - |
            dotnet test --no-build -c ${_BUILD_CONFIG} $REPO_NAME\\TestCore
    id: Test
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
    args:
      - build
      - '-t'
      - '$_IMAGE_NAME:$COMMIT_SHA'
      - .
      - '-f'
      - $_DOCKERFILE_NAME
    dir: $_DOCKERFILE_DIR
    id: Build
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
    args:
      - push
      - '$_IMAGE_NAME:$COMMIT_SHA'
    id: Push
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gke-deploy
    args:
      - prepare
      - '--filename=$_K8S_YAML_PATH'
      - '--image=$_IMAGE_NAME:$COMMIT_SHA'
      - '--app=$_K8S_APP_NAME'
      - '--version=$COMMIT_SHA'
      - '--namespace=$_K8S_NAMESPACE'
      - '--label=$_K8S_LABELS'
      - '--annotation=$_K8S_ANNOTATIONS,gcb-build-id=$BUILD_ID'
      - '--create-application-cr'
      - >-
        --links="Build
        details=https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-build/builds/$BUILD_ID?project=$PROJECT_ID"
      - '--output=output'
    id: Prepare deploy
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gsutil
    args:
      - '-c'
      - |-
        if [ "$_OUTPUT_BUCKET_PATH" != "" ]
        then
          gsutil cp -r output/suggested gs://$_OUTPUT_BUCKET_PATH/config/$_K8S_APP_NAME/$BUILD_ID/suggested
          gsutil cp -r output/expanded gs://$_OUTPUT_BUCKET_PATH/config/$_K8S_APP_NAME/$BUILD_ID/expanded
        fi
    id: Save configs
    entrypoint: sh
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gke-deploy
    args:
      - apply
      - '--filename=output/expanded'
      - '--cluster=$_GKE_CLUSTER'
      - '--location=$_GKE_LOCATION'
      - '--namespace=$_K8S_NAMESPACE'
    id: Apply deploy
images:
  - '$_IMAGE_NAME:$COMMIT_SHA'
options:
  substitutionOption: ALLOW_LOOSE
substitutions:
  _IMAGE_NAME: gcr.io/resolute-land-274909/github_nagydominik_onlineretailer_partial
  _GKE_LOCATION: europe-west3-a
  _K8S_NAMESPACE: default
  _OUTPUT_BUCKET_PATH: resolute-land-274909_cloudbuild/deploy
  _K8S_APP_NAME: productapi
  _K8S_LABELS: ''
  _DOCKERFILE_DIR: ''
  _DOCKERFILE_NAME: Dockerfile_productapi
  _K8S_YAML_PATH: Kubernetes/productapi.yaml
  _GKE_CLUSTER: onlineretailer-cluster
  _K8S_ANNOTATIONS: gcb-trigger-id=cb8757e5-7dce-4aa9-bd43-6c4418f9dacb
tags:
  - gcp-cloud-build-deploy
  - $_K8S_APP_NAME
```

[Cloud Source Repository tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3gMj.png) 
I'm more than sure that Test step is not correct-I've found that code on forum. My goal would be: run the tests and if they fail the whole process should stop, so it would build a new docker image and push it to Container Registry.

Could you provide me some help, how to write this args in the test step?

Comment: With a good fight, you should be able to achieve this. But Is not  a strange pattern to run a CI into a CI ?

Comment: preety sure you can make cloud build do this and as an additional stepp call travis for the tests and then if they are succesful to deploy on app engine, maybe this approach can work for you, let us know

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere: Unfortunately, I fought so hard but it won't work due to windows encryption method which cause a problem on Travis.
It's a strange pattern for sure, but I already have a CD on Google Build and I couldn't find any good solution to run the tests on Google Build, that's the reason I tried Travis for running tests. Could you check my update part in my post, maybe you can help me out!

Comment: @JoséSoní This approach is sound great to be honest but yesterday, after stuck here for whole week, I decided to eliminate Travis and try to run the tests on Google Build before it actually build the application. Can you check my update part in my post, maybe you can help me out?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere can you help me out?

Comment: or @JoséSoní maybe, please?

Comment: Not sure. I never used travis and I never have these errors... Sorry